# Would we "see" some quantum mechanical effects if we investigated with bowling balls instead of photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, determinism

As an layman and outsider who has read some of Dirac, I want an understanding of how important absolute size is to quantum mechanics - like wondering if it is a necessary or sufficient condition (along these lines).

As far as I understand things, like all good theories, quantum mechanics is a mix of empirical data (many of which can't be explained classically), and seasoned induction/intuition/logic. This is where I want to see how absolute size fits in. Is the notion of there being absolute smallness (a scale where there is no way to cause a non-neglibile disturbance upon interaction with it by any means) doing most of the legwork for quantum mechanics?

Would I come up with something resembling quantum mechanics if I ran similar experiments with massive apparatuses like scattering bowling balls, so that I were disturbing *everything* non-negligibly?

Then, why can I not quantify the disturbance (i.e. knowing the momentum, time, etc of my bowling balls) and retrieve a *realistic* picture (as in realism). Sure I may disturb any system I measure like measuring a bird's velocity, but I know the weight of the bird roughly (all birds' momentums are within a few orders of magnitude), I know the details of my bowling ball, so can't I retrieve a realistic, deterministic picture of the world? Here it seems like if you can quantify the disturbance then the non-neglibility or not of it seems no longer important.

Why can I not quantify the disturbances then in quantum mechanics and regain determinism during the measurement process?

I would never dream of anything other than realism in the bowling ball world. Where do I need to begin to ponder something other than realism, as I think is required in the Copenhagen-like interpretations? The fact that there is no sub-photon scale? There is a sub-bowling-ball scale. Is this difference where and why quantum mechanics gets "weird"? That there are limits to all empirical investigations. But if I can reproduce so to speak, a lot of quantum mechanics with a bowling ball world, why not believe quantum mechanics can  be made likewise deterministic. There must be some other weirdness than absolute size right? So is absolute size a red herring, neither sufficient nor necessary? And the legwork is really superposition of states and entanglement, which must be understood agnostic to absolute size? And thus those are what force us to question realism?

Comment: Consider a 1 kg ball whose position you've miraculously  determined with an uncertainty of $1.027×10^{-17}$ m, about 1.2% of the proton radius. The uncertainty in its velocity is greater than $1.027×10^{-17}$ m/s; measuring that requires another miracle. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring is there a typo, did you mean for the position uncertainty to be the same number?

Comment: @electronpusher There's no typo. I calculated that value by doing a square root. The more precise value is $1.026923474×10^{-17}$.

Comment: FWIW, an object moving at $1.027×10^{-17}$ m/s takes almost 3.09 million years to travel 1 millimetre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fundamental constant of nature that establishes the scale over which quantum effects become dominant and readily measured with special tools. It is called *Planck's constant* and it is a very, very tiny number, which means that quantum effects like uncertainty only kick in at very, very tiny length scales.

It is of course possible to apply those same quantum uncertainty rules to macroscopic objects like bowling balls, but the tininess of Planck's constant guarantees that at those large scales, the quantum effects are so very, very, *very* tiny that there is no possible way to measure them- as pointed out by PM 2Ring in his comment.

Note here that if Planck's constant were zero, all quantum effects would vanish, and if it were big, then we would experience quantum weirdness in our everyday lives. The physicist George Gamow wrote a series of books for non-physicists in which the protagonist, Mister Thompkins, gets to experience worlds in which for example Planck's constant is instead large, and explores the (bizarre) consequences.

Comment: Thank you. While this doesn't answer all of my questions, it seems like there are answers I can understand from Gamow and others out there. By you saying we would see quantum weirdness (including entanglement?) with a larger Planck's constant, I still have to wonder why there is this extra mysticism involved in quantum mechanics. Like about realism and can you ask what a particle is doing pre measurement. With your post, it seems like QM is mostly a theory of information and what types of questions can be asked by the experimenter of a subject. Not about the underlying dynamics.

Comment: Shouldn't QM then be seen as a theory in the middle between classical and  deeper, not-currently-accessible layer of dynamical laws. Why did the history of QM go right to Copenhagen, and not something like qbism or even pilot-wave before Copenhagen. Why was taking QM as a purely informational theory not pursued instead of Copenhagen, which forces us to give up determinism and realism (at least in that science can never ask what was going on pre-measurement, purely because of empirical reasons)? Is putting the experimenter in the experiment (a la

Comment: a purely informational perspective of QM) less desirable than giving up determinism and realism, (and possibly some sort of locality since Bell).

Comment: suggest you ask these questions in a series of new posts. -NN

Answer (score 0):

When you go bowling do you invariably score a strike every time? I would guess not.

All the inaccuracies in your aiming and throwing of the ball are quantum effects becoming visible in the chaotic system that your body is. By practicing you can improve the signal to noise ratio of your performance, but you can never reach 100%.

Comment: This sounds incorrect.

Comment: @BBrekke How would you correct it?

Comment: "All the inaccuracies" is surely an overstatement

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Can you think of any other kind of inaccuracy besides probabilistic randomness? Aren't all the noises, thermal, electromagnetic, acoustic, Brownian motion,  etc. based on quantum indeterminacy?

Comment: Sure, if you want to say everything is fundamentally quantum mechanical. But I wouldn't blame QM if I roll a bowling ball way off target, that's just my poor aim

Comment: Your poor aim is just your poor signal to noise ratio.

Comment: Yes - the total noise is surely more than quantum uncertainty (plus the extra assumptions that my aim is unbiased and that each throw is uncorrelated and that somehow we only care about my average throw rather than what happens on an event-to-event basis)